# Apply different bibliography style to specific \printbibliography in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I can use a bibliography style by specifying it in the `usepackage` invocation:

```
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
```

And then I print it with

```
\printbibliography
```

However I have some extra citations with a `keyword = {recommended}` which I can print separately in `printbibliography` with a filter. So far so good. Can I set the bibliography style `reading` to a specific `printbibliography` scope even though the global setting is `alphabetic`?

Something like

```
\printbibliography[title={Citations},notkeyword=recommended]
{
% Somehow set style=reading here
\printbibliography[title={Further reading},keyword=recommended]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it is not possible to use different styles for different `\priontbibliography` calls in a document, but very often it is possible to emulate the behaviour.

The following solution emulates the reading list by copying all the relevant definitions from `reading.bbx`. Then it is just a question of when these definitions are executed, because some settings are used by both bibliographies. Luckily, here all problematic definitions could be delayed until the last minute and there are no clashes. This may not always be possible and in those cases we may have to rename macros or work around this differently.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\InitializeBibliographyStyle{%
  \global\undef\bbx@lasthash}

\defbibenvironment{readingbib}
  {\mkreadingbib
   \list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{0pt}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\bbx@item}
  
\def\bbx@item@false{%
  \itemsep2\bibitemsep
  \item\relax
  \itemsep\bibitemsep}

\def\bbx@item@true{%
  \bbx@item@full}

\def\bbx@item@full{%
  \itemsep2\bibitemsep
  \@itempenalty\z@
  \item\relax
  \begingroup
  \samepage\bfseries
  \def\finentrypunct{\strut}%
  \usebibmacro{entryhead:full}%
  \ifbool{bbx:entrykey}
    {\def\newblockpunct{%
       \nobreak\hskip\z@skip\strut
       \hfill\penalty100\hskip1em\relax
       \hbox{}\nobreak\hfill\strut}%
     \def\finentrypunct{%
       \parfillskip\z@\finalhyphendemerits\z@
       \par\nobreak}%
     \newblock
     \printfield{entrykey}}
    {}%
  \finentry
  \endgroup
  \hrule height 1.25pt\relax
  \itemsep\bibitemsep
  \@itempenalty\@M
  \item\strut
  \@itempenalty\z@}

\def\bbx@item@name{%
  \iffieldequals{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}
    {\bbx@item@false}
    {\itemsep2\bibitemsep
     \@itempenalty\z@
     \item\relax
     \begingroup
     \samepage\bfseries
     \def\finentrypunct{\strut}%
     \usebibmacro{entryhead:name}%
     \finentry
     \endgroup
     \hrule height 1.25pt\relax
     \itemsep\bibitemsep
     \@itempenalty\@M
     \item\strut
     \@itempenalty\z@}}

\newbool{bbx:entrykey}
\newbool{bbx:annotation}
\newbool{bbx:abstract}
\newbool{bbx:library}
\newbool{bbx:file}

\DeclareBiblatexOption{global,type,entry}[boolean]{entryhead}[true]{%
  \ifcsdef{bbx@item@#1}
    {\letcs\bbx@item{bbx@item@#1}}
    {\PackageError{biblatex}
       {Invalid option 'header=#1'}
       {Valid values: header=true, false, full, name.}}}
\DeclareBiblatexOption{global,type,entry}[boolean]{entrykey}[true]{%
  \setbool{bbx:entrykey}{#1}}
\DeclareBiblatexOption{global,type,entry}[boolean]{annotation}[true]{%
  \setbool{bbx:annotation}{#1}}
\DeclareBiblatexOption{global,type,entry}[boolean]{abstract}[true]{%
  \setbool{bbx:abstract}{#1}}
\DeclareBiblatexOption{global,type,entry}[boolean]{library}[true]{%
  \setbool{bbx:library}{#1}}
\DeclareBiblatexOption{global,type,entry}[boolean]{file}[true]{%
  \setbool{bbx:file}{#1}}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{loadfiles,entryhead,entrykey,annotation,abstract,library,file}

\newbibmacro*{entryhead:full}{%
  \printnames[labelname][-1]{labelname}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
  \printfield{labeltitle}}

\newbibmacro*{entryhead:name}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\printfield{labeltitle}}
    {\printnames[labelname]{labelname}}%
  \savefield{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}

\newbibmacro*{entrytail}{%
  \newunit\newblock
  \begingroup
  \def\newblockpunct{\item}%
  \ifbool{bbx:annotation}
    {\usebibmacro{annotation}%
     \newunit\newblock}
    {}%
  \ifbool{bbx:abstract}
    {\usebibmacro{abstract}%
     \newunit\newblock}
    {}%
  \ifbool{bbx:file}
    {\printfield{file}%
     \newunit\newblock}
    {}%
  \ifbool{bbx:library}
    {\printfield{library}%
     \newunit\newblock}
    {}%
  \endgroup}

\newcommand*{\mkreadingbib}{%
  \DeclareNameAlias{author}{default}%
  \DeclareNameAlias{editor}{default}%
  \DeclareNameAlias{translator}{default}%
  %
  \DeclareNameWrapperAlias{author}{default}%
  \DeclareNameWrapperAlias{editor}{default}%
  \DeclareNameWrapperAlias{translator}{default}%
  %
  \DeclareFieldFormat{entrykey}{\mbox{\bfseries##1}}%
  \DeclareFieldFormat{annotation}{\bibstring{annotation}\addcolon\space ##1}%
  \DeclareFieldFormat{abstract}{\bibstring{abstract}\addcolon\space ##1}%
  \DeclareFieldFormat{library}{\bibstring{library}\addcolon\space ##1}%
  \DeclareFieldFormat{file}{\bibstring{file}\addcolon\space \url{##1}}%
  \DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandwidth}{##1}%
  %
  \setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.5\baselineskip}%
  \setlength{\bibparsep}{0pt}%
  %
  \renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
    \ifbibliography
      {\usebibmacro{entrytail}}
      {}%
    \finentry}}
\makeatother


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
  keywords  = {recommended},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
\nocite{elk}

\printbibliography[title={Citations},notkeyword=recommended]
\printbibliography[title={Further reading},keyword=recommended,env=readingbib]
\end{document}
```

[image: Alphabetic style list of citations and reading list]

Comment: How would you modify your code to only show the list of  references in the "Further reading" without any hline, nothing. Maybe itemize the list?

Comment: @JonathanPrieto-Cubides I suggest you ask a  new question with your explicit requirements. You don't have to copy the code from the `reading` style. You can make things "visually lighter".

Comment: Done: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661214/list-of-references-within-a-section